# Using my own content provider like default ones

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

I want to implement my own content provider as an Android project, and implement an App to use the content provider in another Android project. By this way I will have 2 AndroidManifest.xml files, one for the content provider and another for the App. The usage is similar to the  default content providers such as Contact.

My question is how to run the content provider.

A. Do I need to start the content provider by an activity, and register itself by provider.../provider in the AndroidManifest.xml?

or

B. Can I implement the content provider as a library? I tried it but got exception "Unknown URL content". How is the provider registered by this way?

Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: just use ContentResolver.query, inseet, delete etc... with your ContentProvider's Uri

Comment: My question is how to run the content provider. A or B? Because the App and the provider are in 2 different projects, starting the App does not start the provider automatically unless it is a library.

Comment: It seems the provider does not register its URI if it is implemented as a library.